# Modifying input that's created by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to create html-objects with jQuery and then delete them again via jQuery/javascript but I run in issues because these objects didn't exist when the page was loaded.
Do you have any ideas on how I may solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

(This is my first post on stackoverflow - I hope I did everything right ^^)

https://jsbin.com/yudamofoho/edit

```html
<body>
  <div id='ipt-list'>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="btn-add" value="Add">
</body>
```

```js
function rmInput(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
}
$(function(){
  $('#btn-add').on('click', function(){
        ipt = '<div><input type="text" value=""><input type="submit" onclick="rmInput();" class="btn-rm" value="Remove"></div>';
        $('#ipt-list').append(ipt);
        return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the [**`Window`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object not the element you are thinking.

You have to pass [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to the function so that you can refer that inside the function:

```
onclick="rmInput(this);"
```

```js
function rmInput(el){
  //console.log(this.constructor.name); // Window
  $(el).parent().remove();
  return false;
}

$(function(){
  $('#btn-add').on('click', function(){
    ipt = '<div><input type="text" value=""><input type="submit" onclick="rmInput(this);" class="btn-rm" value="Remove"></div>';
    $('#ipt-list').append(ipt);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='ipt-list'>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="btn-add" value="Add">
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're using the outdated `onclick` attribute. Within the function it invokes `this` will refer to the `window`, not the element which raised the event.

To fix this, and improve your logic, remove the inline event handler and use a delegated one instead:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#btn-add').on('click', function() {
    let ipt = '<div><input type="text" value=""><input type="button" class="btn-rm" value="Remove"></div>';
    $('#ipt-list').append(ipt);
  });

  $('#ipt-list').on('click', '.btn-rm', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ipt-list"></div>
<input type="button" id="btn-add" value="Add">
```

Also note that I changed both buttons to `type="button"`. If you're going to cancel the event in both cases, the `submit` type becomes redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery you don't need to put inline onclick event.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#btn-add').on('click', function(){
  ipt = '<div><input type="text" value=""><input type="submit" class="btn-rm" value="Remove"></div>';
  $('#ipt-list').append(ipt);
  return false;
  });
  
  $('#ipt-list').on('click', '.btn-rm', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id='ipt-list'>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="btn-add" value="Add">
</body>
```